# Spring boot not call controller for guest user

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a view to retrieve the password that is as public, but does not call the controller, it only works if the user logs in and enters this view through the url. I am usiing spring boot 1.5.14 with spring security.

```
function validar(){
        var codigo= $('#codigo').val();
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : "/host/validar",
            data: {
                "codigo" : codigo
            },
            success: function(result) {
               alert("success");
            },
            error : function(e) {
               alert("error");
            }
        });
    }
```

the html with thymeleaf

```
<div class="x_content">
 <section class="text-center">
  <h5><span>Ingrese codigo</span></h5>
  <form id="formValidar">
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="codigo" required="" id="codigo" name="codigo" />
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-dark" type="button" onclick="validar()">Validar</button>
    </div>
  </form>
 </section>
</div>
```

the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/validar", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String validar(
        @RequestParam("codigo") String codigo){
    System.out.println("entro sdgsdgdsg");
    System.out.println("codigo: "+codigo);
    Usuario usuario = usuarioService.buscarPorCodigo(codigo);
    if (usuario == null){
       return "pagina-validar";
    }
    return "nueva-pagina";
}
```

edit: add config security.

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**","/images/**","/build/**","/vendors/**","/recuperar-clave","/nueva-clave").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .successHandler(successHandler)
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().permitAll();
}
```

Comment: What is your spring security config ? by default, if spring security is found on the classpath, a basic auth is set on every endpoint of the application.

Comment: @AkliREGUIG I just edited, adding the configuration, I do not know if you mean that.

Comment: Use the developer tool of your browser and check the network tab and the xhr requests. Your request should be there and you can compare the request data/headers your browser are sending with your controller's expectations.

Comment: @m4gic I do not know much about the developer tool, but I see different information coming out, using google chrome the following thing: if it is not logged in the name column I get a login and if I click it shows the login view and in initiator the method validar(). when the user is logged in I get the url with the get method with the validate function and its parameters, and the initiator is the jquery.min library